# Remove space at the end of html in electron

Tags: javascript, html, electron

My electron application shows me a space at the end of the HTML. I am not able to adjust it to the size of the window. I think the problem is in the electron configuration and not in the HTML.

[image]
[image]

I have already tried with:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

But it seems that the window ends before the end space.
My Electron window configuration is:

```
const win = new BrowserWindow({
    // fullscreen: true,
    alwaysOnTop: !isDevelopment,
    frame: isDevelopment,
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    transparent: true,
    webPreferences: {
      // Use pluginOptions.nodeIntegration, leave this alone
      // See nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/security.html#node-integration for more info
      nodeIntegration: process.env.ELECTRON_NODE_INTEGRATION,
      contextIsolation: !process.env.ELECTRON_NODE_INTEGRATION,
      devTools: isDevelopment
    }
  })
```

I need to adjust the height of the html to the entire window, removing the scroll.

Comment: have you ever tried overflow-y hidden in css  ? try to add to the body, it should at least hide the scrolling. more info here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.php

Comment: @FaFa Yes, but that only hides the scroll. When the screen size is larger than the HTML, when interacting with the web and opening dialogs, the scroll moves and the white space remains visible.